# How to write a JSON file using Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I need to write a JSON file using Ansible, using the `shell` module.

But it gives this error:

> TASK [Generate certs] **********************************************************
> fatal: [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cfssl gencert -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem -config=ca-config.json -profile=kubernetes kube-controller-manager-csr.json | cfssljson -bare kube-controller-manager                     \n", "delta": "0:00:00.015363", "end": "2020-08-14 16:26:35.643003", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-08-14 16:26:35.627640", "stderr": "Failed to load config file: {"code":5200,"message":"could not read configuration file"}Failed to parse input: unexpected end of JSON input", "stderr_lines": ["Failed to load config file: {"code":5200,"message":"could not read configuration file"}Failed to parse input: unexpected end of JSON input"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
> PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
> 35.246.9.221               : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

And this is the playbook for this:

```yaml
---
- hosts: kube_master
  tasks:
    - name: Create kube-controller-manager.pem &kube-controller-manager-key.pem
      # become: true      
      shell: |
        cat > kube-controller-manager-csr.json << EOF
        {
          "CN": "system:kube-controller-manager",
          "key": {
            "algo": "rsa",
            "size": 2048
          },
          "names": [
            {
              "C": "US",
              "L": "Portland",
              "O": "system:kube-controller-manager",
              "OU": "Kubernetes The Hard Way",
              "ST": "Oregon"
            }
          ]
        }
        EOF        
                 

    - name: Generate certs
      shell: |
        cfssl gencert \
        -ca=ca.pem \
        -ca-key=ca-key.pem \
        -config=ca-config.json \
        -profile=kubernetes \
        kube-controller-manager-csr.json | cfssljson -bare kube-controller-manager
```

Can someone tell me more about this error and why it is happening?

Comment: (a) do you have `ca-config.json` and have you ensured **it** is sane? (b) you are abusing the `shell:` command, when what you actually want is [`copy:` with `content:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html#parameter-content) `- copy: dest: kube-controller-manager-csr.json content: "put your JSON here"` _(with apologies that comments don't support newlines)_

Comment: Like @mdaniel said, or if you really want your json in the playbook, make it [a dictionary in YAML](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics), then apply a [`to_json` filter to it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) while using the `copy` with `content: "{{ my_var | to_json }}"`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε can you give me a small example? I am new to `ansible`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε here what is meant by `my_var` ? And where should I put it?

Answer (score 11):

So what you can do, if you really want to keep your data in the playbook itself is to translate your JSON data in a [dictionary in YAML](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics).

An equivalent representation of your actual JSON would be:

```yaml
certificate: 
  CN: system:kube-controller-manager
  key: 
    algo: rsa
    size: 2048
  names:
    - C: US
      L: Portland
      O: system:kube-controller-manager
      OU: Kubernetes The Hard Way
      ST: Oregon
```

Then, based on this, you could simply apply a [`to_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) on top of it, before using the [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html) module with the [`content`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html#parameter-content) parameter.

So given this task:

```yaml
- copy:
    dest: kube-controller-manager-csr.json
    content: "{{ certificate | to_json }}" 
  vars: 
    certificate: 
      CN: system:kube-controller-manager
      key: 
        algo: rsa
        size: 2048
      names:
        - C: US
          L: Portland
          O: system:kube-controller-manager
          OU: Kubernetes The Hard Way
          ST: Oregon
```

We end up with this *kube-controller-manager-csr.json* file

```json
{"CN": "system:kube-controller-manager", "key": {"algo": "rsa", "size": 2048}, "names": [{"C": "US", "L": "Portland", "O": "system:kube-controller-manager", "OU": "Kubernetes The Hard Way", "ST": "Oregon"}]}
```

---

Some extra notes:

- Here, the JSON is not really human readable (all is in one line). If this is causing you an issue, you can switch from using `to_json` filter to using [`to_nice_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data)
- [YAML is a natural superset of JSON](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759572), this means that you can actually use a JSON structure as a valid YAML variable.
  I wouldn't do it, though, because I find it odd to mix two languages in YAML files, but if you personnaly see no objection to it, this playbook, that doesn't even use the `to_json` filter, is also a working one:

  ```yaml
  - copy:
      dest: kube-controller-manager-csr.json
      content: "{{ certificate }}" 
    vars: 
      certificate: {
        "CN": "system:kube-controller-manager",
        "key": {
          "algo": "rsa",
          "size": 2048
        },
        "names": [
          {
            "C": "US",
            "L": "Portland",
            "O": "system:kube-controller-manager",
            "OU": "Kubernetes The Hard Way",
            "ST": "Oregon"
          }
        ]
      }
  ```